Livewire search does not work, I get an error "Uncaught Snapshot missing on Livewire component with id: GNJ2OeHRPh4jt67U30uG"
I have such a component
<div class="right-board">
    <div class="caption-h-btn mobile-wrap">
        <h1>@lang('app.My ad')</h1>
        <div class="small-search-field">
            <i class="ico-search"></i>
            <input type="text" wire:model="search" wire:keydown.enter="searchAd()"
                   placeholder="@lang('app.Search')">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-wrapper">
        <div class="overflow-scroll-box">
            <ul class="head-tab like-button2 white-space-nowrap">
                <li><a href="#adv1"
                       @if ($activeTab == '#adv1') class="active" @endif>@lang('app.Active') {{count($active)}}</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#adv2"
                       @if ($activeTab == '#adv2') class="active" @endif>@lang('app.Fail') {{count($fail)}}</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#adv6"
                       @if ($activeTab == '#adv6') class="active" @endif>@lang('app.Lock') {{count($locked)}}</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#adv3"
                       @if ($activeTab == '#adv3') class="active" @endif>@lang('app.Archive') {{count($archive)}}</a></li>
                <li><a href="#adv4"
                       @if ($activeTab == '#adv4') class="active" @endif>@lang('app.Notes') {{count($note)}}</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#adv5"
                       @if ($activeTab == '#adv5') class="active" @endif>@lang('app.Moderation') {{count($moderation)}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="body-tab {{$activeTab == '#adv1' ? 'active' : ''}}" id="adv1">
            @foreach($active as $item)
                <div class="box-board-border">
                    <livewire:ad-profile :key="'ad-profile-'.$item->id.'-tab1'" :item="$item"/>
                </div>
            @endforeach
            @if (count($active) == 0)
                <p class="clean-tab-text">@lang('app.Not found')</p>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="body-tab {{$activeTab == '#adv2' ? 'active' : ''}}" id="adv2">
            @foreach ($fail as $item)
                <div class="box-board-border">
                    <livewire:ad-profile :key="'ad-profile-'.$item->id.'-tab2'" :item="$item"/>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="body-tab {{$activeTab == '#adv6' ? 'active' : ''}}" id="adv6">
            @foreach ($locked as $item)
                <div class="box-board-border">
                    <livewire:ad-profile :key="'ad-profile-'.$item->id.'-tab6'" :item="$item"/>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="body-tab {{$activeTab == '#adv3' ? 'active' : ''}}" id="adv3">
            @foreach ($archive as $item)
                <div class="box-board-border">
                    <livewire:ad-profile :key="'ad-profile-'.$item->id.'-tab3'" :item="$item"/>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="body-tab {{$activeTab == '#adv4' ? 'active' : ''}}" id="adv4">
            @foreach ($note as $item)
                <div class="box-board-border">
                    <livewire:ad-profile :key="'ad-profile-'.$item->id.'-tab4'" :item="$item"/>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="body-tab {{$activeTab == '#adv5' ? 'active' : ''}}" id="adv5">
            @foreach ($moderation as $item)
                <div class="box-board-border">
                    <livewire:ad-profile :key="'ad-profile-'.$item->id.'-tab5'" :item="$item"/>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
    @push('scripts')
        <script>
            $(function () {
                const el = $('.overflow-scroll-box')
                const leftOffset = el.find('a.active').position().left;
                el.scrollLeft(leftOffset);
            })
        </script>
    @endpush
</div>

And I am facing a very strange error. For example, if I search for an ad by number and it is the first in the list (in my tab), then everything works as it should. If it is the second or later, then I get an error: Uncaught Snapshot missing on Livewire component with id: GNJ2OeHRPh4jt67U30uG
Why this behavior? Can this be fixed?

Do you set another key in the <livewire:ad-profile ...> component? If yes, unset it and leave the code above as is.

I didn't quite understand your question

In the file resources/views/livewire/ad-profile.blade.php, did you add another :key="$your_id"? If so, drop it and try again. Your error reminds me to such situation.

The problem was solved by adding Str::random(16) to the keys :key="'ad-profile-'.$item->id.'-tab4-'.Str::random(16)"
